# How can I reference the Gracenote sdk in my project?

Tags: gracenote

I want to create a music fingerprinting program for windows with C# using the gnsdk .The problem is that even though in the documentation it talks about initialization and all the methods I can't find how to actually import the sdk to start using all these functions.
I am relatively new to programming so please be kind thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the Gracenote C# Web API Library by adding it to your project via NuGet.

**You can do this in the Package Manager UI within Visual Studio**

1. **Project** → **Manage NuGet Packages**
2. Choose "**nuget.org**" as the Package source (top-right)
3. Select the **Browse** tab
4. Search for **ParkSquare.GraceNote**
5. Select that package in the list
6. Click **Install**.

### Now you can work with GraceNote

```
using ParkSquare.GraceNote;
```

More information on alternative ways to use NuGet packages and how they work here:

[Quickstart: Install and use a package in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)

### But what if I don't want to use NuGet?

Okay, each to their own I guess.

1. Download the **Class Library (.dll)** files for **ParkSquare GraceNote**
2. Navigate to the **Solution Explorer** window in Visual Studio
3. Under the current **Project** → Right-click the **References** item
4. Click **Add Reference** and **Browse** to the files

Nice and simple. I hope that helps anyone reading this.